# Clear overlay except first time marker is created

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a function to get coordinates from database and a function to set marker(`setMarker()`). I check database using `setInterval(setMarker())` and update marker by calling `setMarker()`if the location has changed.

I check if it's the first time I'm creating the marker and not updating it, if not, I `markerArray[i].setMap(null)`. The second time I enter the loop I try to set to null. But I get an error saying `markerArray` is undefined.

The checking is done inside a `foreach` loop which has to loop upto the length of the (number of location coordinates) and then I set to null.

```
       function setMarker(){
        var markerArray = [];
        latArray.forEach(function(lat, i) {
            //                marker = new google.maps.Marker();
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<div id="content>' + '<p style="color:#000000">DeviceID:<p>' + '<p>' + deviceId[i] + '</p>' + '</div>'
            });
            if(markerCount >(latArray.length)) //check if marker is created for first time,if not, set to null
            {
                //console.log("!------------------");
                //console.log(marker); 


            }
            else{    //if first time, increment so that next time marker can be set to null to create new marker in new position
                markerCount++;

                console.log("else"+markerCount);
            }

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                //position: new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i], lngArray[i]),
                icon: "phone6.png"
            });
            markerArray.push(marker);
            //console.log(markerArray[i]);
            markerArray[i].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(latArray[i],lngArray[i])); //marker undefined here
            markerArray[i].addListener("click", function() {
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                //marker.setMap(null);
            });

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try indexing markers with unique ids like following ...

```
var getMarkerUniqueId = function(lat, lng) {
    return lat + '_' + lng;
};
```

and then you can trace particular marker..